# Alternative of float or double in laravel-8

Tags: laravel-8

I can do

```
$table->integer('money'); //for integer nubmer 1,2,3,...,99999
```

But I want the same thing for a floating numbers like 1.5,2.3,3.3,...,99999.5

```
$table->_______('money');// what is in in this blank?
```

How to do it in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use
this code

```
$table->double('money');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).